# XGBoost Feature Importance Mismatch

Tags: python, xgboost

I get different values of the importances when I use `model.feature_importances_` versus `xgb.plot_importance(model)`.

Moreover, the numpy array feature_importances do not directly correspond to the indexes that are returned from the plot_importance function.

Here is what the plot looks like:

[image: xgb.plot_importance(model)]

But this is the output of model.feature_importances_ gives entirely different values:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.13636364,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01136364,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07386363,
        0.03409091,  0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.01704546,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.05681818,  0.15909091,  0.0625    ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.10227273,  0.        ,  0.07386363,
        0.01704546,  0.05113636,  0.00568182,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.02272727,  0.        ,  0.01136364,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.11363637,  0.        ,  0.01704546,  0.01136364,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ], dtype=float32)
```

If I just try to grab Feature 81 (`model.feature_importances_[81]`), I get:`0.051136363`. However `model.feature_importances_.argmax()` returns `72`.

Any idea why these two methods give me qualitatively different results?